# Optimizing method with list of 500k+ elements

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm looking for some help since I don't know how to optimize a process.

I have to invoke a service that returns a list with more than 500K elements (I don't know why, these services belongs to the client), per each element of the list, I have to invoke 2 more services and then save some attributes in our database, this last step is not the problem, but the entire process took between 1 and 2 seconds per element, so with this time is going to take like more of 100 hours to complete the process.
My approach is the following, I have my main method, inside this method I get the large list, then I use a parallelStream to iterate in the elements of the list and then I use a CompletableFuture to call the method that invokes the 2 services mentioned above. I've tried changing the parallelStream  to stream and for-each , tried to split the main list into smaller lists and many other things but I don't see a better performance, I think the problem is the invocation of those 2 services but I want to try luck asking here.

I'm using java 11, spring, and for the invocation of the services I'm using RestTemplate, and this is my code:

```
public void updateDiscount() {
    //List with 500k elements        
    var relationshipList = relationshipService.getLargeList();
    //CompletableFuture to make the async calls to the method above
    relationshipList.parallelStream().forEach(level1 -> {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> relationshipService.asyncDiscountSave(level1));        
    });

}


//Second class
@Async("nameOfThePool")
 public void asyncDiscountSave(ElementOfList element) {
     //Logic to create request
     //.........
     var responseClients = anotherClass.getClients(element.getGroup1()) //get the first response with restTemplate
     var responseProducts = anotherClass.getProducts(element.getGroup2())//get the second response with restTemplate
     
     for (var client : responseClients) {
         for (var product : responseProducts) {
            //Here we just save some attributes of these objects on our DB
         }
     } 

 }
```

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

For this particular case, the only improvement that I can do is to pass a thread pool to the completable future, the problem is the response time of the services that I need to invoke.

I decided to follow a second approach and it took like 5 hours to complete, compared with the first approach this is acceptable.

Comment: Are those two services or the elements of the list related/dependent to each other in any way?

Comment: @GauthamM Yes, I have to save the relation between client-product and other attribute of the main list

Comment: So, is it required to loop all the products for each client? Also, I am assuming that `element` would be passed as parameter to `getClients` and `getProducts`.

Comment: @GauthamM yeah, you right, I've edited the code with that. The nested loop is mandatory for that reason.

Comment: "I think the problem is the invocation of those 2 services" - I'd say so too. 1M REST service calls are bound to take a while and the provider might not even be happy you're doing so. This is what you'd need to tackle, e.g. by looking for a bulk operation to reduce the number of calls needed. If that doesn't exist get in touch with the provider/client to provide it. An alternative _might_ be to detect elements for which you don't have to call the services if you can somehow detect you already have the data.

Comment: In general the API you're describing already feels badly designed or you just don't use it in the correct way. If those updates happen often and are distributed over time another approach might be to use events and update your database whenever the element data changes (i.e. an appropriate event is published).

Comment: @snake_404 if multiple elements fall under the same group, you could identify those unique groups and then invoke the 2 service calls for each unique group.

Comment: you do not need to guess - measure. even if simple `long end = start - System.nanoTime()`. This will shed a lot more light than you simply trying to guess where the time is really spent.

Comment: After a lot of tests, there is no way to optimize the operations for this particular case, the only improvement is to pass a thread pool to the completable future. I decided to follow a second approach where I need to invoke 3 more services in different hours, then store the result on the database, this process took like 5 hours but is acceptable for our process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you haven't defined an executor you are using the default pool. Adding an executor allow you to create many threads as you needed and the server resources can manage

```
public void updateDiscount() {
  Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 100 );//Define the number according to server resources performance
    //List with 500k elements        
    var relationshipList = relationshipService.getLargeList();
    //CompletableFuture to make the async calls to the method above
    relationshipList.parallelStream().forEach(level1 -> {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> relationshipService.asyncDiscountSave(level1), executor);        
    });

}
```